# Is it possible to store lambda expression in array C#

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

I'm writing a game AI engine and I'd like to store some lambda expressions/delegates (multiple lists of arguments) in an array.

Something like that:

```
 _events.Add( (delegate() { Debug.Log("OHAI!"); }) );
 _events.Add( (delegate() { DoSomethingFancy(this, 2, "dsad"); }) );
```

Is it possible in C#?

Comment: It seems like you want to store "callback" methods more than you want lambda expressions.

Comment: or a List<Delegate> ... yes you can...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can make a `List<Action>` instead:

```
List<Action> _events = new List<Action>();
_events.Add( () => Debug.Log("OHAI!")); //for only a single statement
_events.Add( () =>
    {
        DoSomethingFancy(this, 2, "dsad");
        //other statements
    });
```

Then call an individual item:

```
_events[0]();
```

Answer (score 6):

you can use System.Action.

```
var myactions = new List<Action>();
myactions .Add(new Action(() => { Console.WriteLine("Action 1"); }) 
myactions .Add(new Action(() => { Console.WriteLine("Action 2"); }) 

foreach (var action in myactions)
  action();
```