# alternatives to switch-case

Tags: c#, switch-statement, controls, sequence

I want to know if this kind of switch-case usage is appropriate, or there is any other alternatives (patterns)?

the following is part of my program:

the basics is I am doing a sequence of actions

1. generally program control is following the sequence of case one by one;
2. usually any specific case is not finished in its first call, we have to wait until the procX `return`s `true`. (waiting for instrument response or action completion);
3. jump to a specific `case` is possible (changing `StepCurrent` in the sampling code).

I found this kind of `switch`-`case` is hard to maintain, especially by changing the `StepCurrent` to direct control flow. And code looks ugly.

is there any better method?

note: though I am using C#, the problem might not be limited to it.

```
    while (true)
        {
            if (sig_IsExit())
            {
                break;
            }

            Thread.Sleep(500);

            bRetSts = false;
            switch (StepCurrent) // nSeq)
            {
                case 0:
                     bRetSts = proc0();
                     break;

                case 1:

                     bRetSts = proc1();
                    break;
                case 2:
                     bRetSts = proc2();
                    break;

                case 3:
                     bRetSts = proc3();
                    break;

                case 4:
                   ...
            }

            if( bRetSts )
                StepCurrent++;
        }
```

Comment: You could use state pattern. Every proc is used in each state. Than You can change to the next state

Comment: You could Create a dictionary with the number as key and the function delegate as value. This would make the Code a bit smaller.

Comment: Create an array of Func<Boolean> similar to Action in this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23477823/is-it-possible-to-store-lambda-expression-in-array-c-sharp

Comment: this seems fine.  something inevitable is, when some day a new proc is inserted, for example between proc0 and proc1, I have to update any reference to the previous proc1, which is now proc2. -  this kind of headache might be inevitable.

Answer (score 12):

You can use a `Dictionary<int,Func<bool>>` , with this you will have less cyclomatic complexity, see the example:

> Note: i use *Dictionary* to show that you can use any type as key, for example a `string` with a name, or an `enum`.

```
Dictionary<int,Func<bool>> proc = new Dictionary<int,Func<bool>>
{
   {0, proc0},
   {1, proc1},
   {2, proc2},
   {3, proc3},
}
```

and than use like that:

```
  while (true)
    {
        if (sig_IsExit())
           break;
        Thread.Sleep(500);

        bRetSts = false;
        bRetSts = proc[StepCurrent]();

        if( bRetSts )
            StepCurrent++;
    }
```

Comment: this seems fine.  something inevitable is, when some day a new proc is inserted, for example between proc0 and proc1, I have to update any reference to the previous proc1, which is now proc2. -  this kind headache might be inevitable.

Answer (score 2):

```
bRetSts = (StepCurrent == 0)? proc0():
          (StepCurrent == 1)? proc1():
          (StepCurrent == 2)? proc2():
          (StepCurrent == 3)? proc3():
          false; // it could be more proper to throw an exception
```

or, perhaps more appropriate if all `procX` have the same signature:

```
var funcs = new Func<bool>[] { proc0, proc1, proc2, proc3 };
funcs[StepCurrent]();
```

Comment: o.o, i will do that too, kkkkk

Answer (score 0):

I think this is perfect opportunity to use Chain of responsibility design pattern.

Here is one of the better descriptions I found: https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/chain_of_responsibility Also example of implementation: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/chain_of_responsibility_pattern.htm

Comment: That was my second thought. But there is no stepping back. So the chain of resp. wouldn't use case 1 after using case 2. I would use chain of responsibility, if it is possible. It's not clear from the question.